# How to make external dependencies on a shared items project in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am in need of sharing some header files between two different projects. So I created a shared items project, and now I can't figure out how to add external dependencies to it, so I could use includes from the WDK 10 shared folder. Did anyone run into this problem before? I can still add external dependencies on a library project, but somehow not on shared items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cross-platform-code-sharing-with-visual-c/) says

> These “shared items” projects don’t participate in build but they can
> contain any number of C++ headers and sources.

And you need to add the dependencies to the actual build project.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to work. I first created the header files inside an actual project to make sure the usage of external classes is appropriate, then moved everything to shared project - it started marking all external references as invalid, but after compilation all these errors were resolved.